# Multiclass classification Imbalance in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset I'm working on which is of the form:

```
Feature1 Feature2 Feature3 Class
 0.1       0.2      0.3     Apple
 0.3       0.1     0.4     Orange
 0.12       0.22      0.13     Banana
 0.112      0.231      0.3     Watermelon
```

Consider my dataset has a total of 40,000 observations and 22,000 of them are of watermelon class. How can I handle an Imbalanced multi-class problem as shown above in python?

Comment: AFAIK smote should work fine on onehot encoded data

Comment: Added an answer on how this could be handled with smote. Also, I'd suggest you to include in the question what you've tried, and that you've had problems with smote, so that the question has any chance to be reopened, presumably that was the reason for it to be closed

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach in these cases is to either undersample the majoritary class or oversample the minoritary classes. Though these aren't necessarily the best way to go. That will always depend on the problem at hand, and on the model you'll be using. Applying sample weights for instance is also a common approach.

Since oversampling has been mentioned in the comments,
here's how we could use [`SMOTE`](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html) to oversample the minoritary classes. Note that `SMOTE` expects numerical features, so you'll have to OneHot encode the categorical data (the label *can* be categorical though, this only applies to categorical features, so if you don't have any this step wouln't be necessary). We can use a [`Pipiline`](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) for convenience. Also note that you should be using `imblearn'`s `Pipeline` when using `SMOTE`, since it includes additional methods not contemplated in the scikit-learn counterpart that are necessary when the shape of the input data will be changed.

Let's create an unbalanced classification problem from the sample dataframe:

```
df = df.append(pd.concat([df.iloc[[0]]]*200))
df = df.append(pd.concat([df.iloc[[1]]]*2000))
df = df.append(pd.concat([df.iloc[[2]]]*100))
df = df.append(pd.concat([df.iloc[[3]]]*300))

df.Class.value_counts()

Orange        2001
Watermelon     301
Apple          201
Banana         101
Name: Class, dtype: int64
```

So in order to have an unbiased estimator, we want to balance these classes. Let's build a pipeline, including a [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) and the `SMOTE` oversampler:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline

X = df.drop(['Class'],1)
y = df.Class

steps = [('onehot', OneHotEncoder()), ('smt', SMOTE())]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)

X, y = pipeline.fit_resample(X, y)
```

Now, by taking the `value_counts` on the target, we'd get:

```
pd.Series(y.to_numpy()).value_counts()

Banana        2001
Orange        2001
Watermelon    2001
Apple         2001
dtype: int64
```

Also, we might not be interested in oversampling all other classes up to the same amount as the majoritary class. In such cases, `SMOTE` allows to feed a dictionary specifying the amount of samples for each targeted class:

```
smote_samples = {'Apple':1000, 'Orange':2001, 'Banana':1000, 'Watermelon':1000}

steps = [('onehot', OneHotEncoder()), ('smt', SMOTE(smote_samples))]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)
```

Giving in this case:

```
X, y = pipeline.fit_resample(X, y)
pd.Series(y.to_numpy()).value_counts()

Orange        2001
Banana        1000
Apple         1000
Watermelon    1000
dtype: int64
```